# When do definable functions have definable inverses?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Are there any conditions on a structure so that every definable function also has a definable inverse?

Comment: What is meant here by “definable?”

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didn't have anything specific in mind, it could be $\emptyset$-definable or definable with parameters. It's just a general open-ended question I had.

Comment: (1) If a definable function has an inverse, the inverse is always definable. (2) If a structure has more than one element, the constant function with value $c$ is definable (using $c$ as a parameter) and has no inverse.

Comment: If you say “definable with parameters”, then constant functions are definable. Thus, all functions are definable if and only if the model has at most one element.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh, is (1) the case by simply swapping the variables? If $\theta(x,y)$ defines $f(x)$, then $\theta^{-1}(x,y):=\theta(y,x)$ defines $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: @AlvaroP. Yep  !

Comment: @AlexKruckman OK thank you, I should've seen that. I have a bad habit of not trying things myself first.